# hide pagination links if there is just one page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.3.

I know that how can paginate large data set and how to work it.

Pagination links shown Even if just one page is require to show result. but I want to hide pagination links in this case?

I use `render()` method to show pagination links like this :

```
<nav id="pagination">
  {!! $posts->render() !!}
</nav>
```

Any idea?

Comment: From the [twitter](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/772043042261827584), it's a bug in L5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I want to apply this behavior to all paginations on the whole laravel project ,I used @Vuldo suggested approach to  `default.blade.php` view in the `resources/views/vendor/pagination` directory like this :

```
@if($paginator->total() > $paginator->perPage())
     <ul class="pagination">
        ...
     </ul>
@endif
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way to handle this is to hide the links to the pagination in your front-end if `total <= per_page`.

If you're using laravel's `links()` method you can do the following:

```
@if($results->total() > $results->perPage())
 {{ $results->links }}
@endif
```

Comment: I'am using `render()` function to show links.what is difference between two?

Comment: You are using `render()` inside of your view? Can you update your post with your code please?

Comment: @valdo, yes I'm using `render()`. I updated my post.

Comment: To be honest, I don't even know what is the `render()` it looks like it's the same

Answer (score 1):

Here is better approach by undocumented method, for Laravel 5.0 and later.

```php
@if ($results->hasPages())
    {{ $results->links() }}
@endif
```

Link to method:

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/Paginator.html#method_hasPages